# How to write sderaster commands

Tags: sderaster

I am trying to receive information about a Raster image in an sde Database. I am using the sderaster -o list command which gives me the error "ERROR: No  [opotions]".

I have tried to enter all the possible combinations of raster name, but I can´t get further with it. I am guessing that table refers to the dataset name. but what about the connection paramaters or database name? Does sderaster only work with sde services, or also with direct connect?

Version: Arcsde 9.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NOTE: The use of ArcSDE command-line utilities was deprecated at ArcGIS 10.1 and removed after ArcGIS 10.2. ArcSDE server connections were removed after 10.2 as well, so Direct Connect is now the *only* supported connection protocol, and the syntax is *different* from the UI and Python tools. This answer should be considered *obsolete*, and is only present for historic purposes.

---

There's also a usage listing after the message, that indicates the '-l' parameter is required.:

```
C:\Temp> sderaster -o list

Error: No <table,column> specified.

ArcSDE   10.1
Raster   Utility
----------------------------------------------------------------
Usage: sderaster -o list -l <table,column> [options]

The command specific options are:
                [-verbose]
                [-storage]
                [-v <raster id> [-L <pyramid level>]] | -W <where>]
                [-V <version name>]

The common connection options are:
                [-i <service> | <port#>]
                [-s <server>]
                [-D <database>]
                [-u <username>]
                [-p <password>]

Incomplete...
```

All command-line utilities (except 'sdemon') have the option of using Direct Connect if you specify the "-i sde:*options*" per the documentation for your RDBMS.  For SQL-Server you'd need to specify "-I sde:sqlserver:serverhost -D databasename -u login -p password" (or use the environment variable equivalents).

Note that "raster layers" are tables, and the rasters themselves are *rows* in those tables.  Knowing the table name and row identifier are critical to using command-line utilities.  You *could have found* an example of the use pattern for command-line tools like 'sderaster' in the *se_toolkit documentation* (but that FTP server has been decommissioned).